# OSX rgbdslam install via indigo

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rosdep-install, rgbdslamv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

#On Hold

Holding off on rgbdslam install to El Capitan until ros libs progress for osx 10.11+

*interim solution was to install rgbdslam v2 via ros indigo + Ubuntu 14.04 + rEFind for osx*

---

ROS Indigo took some work to install on OSX El Captian (10.11.3) but it works now.

At this point I can attempt to install rgbdslam

```
$ rosdep install rgbdslam
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
$ rosdep install rgbdslam
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rgbdslam: No definition of [libdevil-dev] for OS [osx]
```

I have devIL installed via brew:

```
$ brew install devil
Warning: devil-1.7.8_1 already installed
```

At this point I'm stuck. What should I do?

** EDIT **

- Tried installing [libdevil from source](https://github.com/LuaDist/libdevil), unsuccessfully.
- Installed libdevil via macports. Didn't help so I uninstalled macports since brew is my preferred package manager.

** EDIT **

- Set `siftgpu_disable_devil = 0` in `SiftGPU/makefile`
- `set(ENV{SIFT_GPU_MODE} 0)` in `CMakeLists.txt`

I'm still seeing `rgbdslam: No definition of [libdevil-dev] for OS [osx]`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225798/osx-rgbdslam-install-via-indigo/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-02-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try removing the dependency from rgbdslam/package.

Should you get compilation/linking problems, try to set the CMake-Variable USE_SIFT_GPU to 0 (e.g., using cmake-gui). SiftGPU is the thing in rgbdslam that needs libdevil

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-02-06**:
I set `siftgpu_disable_devil = 0` in `SiftGPU/makefile` and `set(ENV{SIFT_GPU_MODE}  0)` in `CMakeLists.txt` with no avail. I'm still seeing `rgbdslam: No definition of [libdevil-dev] for OS [osx]`

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-02-08**:
And have you removed the dependency in package.xml?

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-02-08**:
Commenting devIL out in package.xml put me a little further but into some seemingly OSX specific issues, trying to resolve those via github. Will respond here once I have a solution. Thanks for your assistance.